# Inaccessible class members while overloading operators

Tags: c++

I have the class:

```
class Fraction{
    friend Fraction operator+(Fraction& f1, Fraction& f2);
    friend Fraction operator-(Fraction& f1, Fraction& f2);
    friend Fraction operator*(Fraction& f1, Fraction& f2);
    friend Fraction operator/(Fraction& f1, Fraction& f2);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& cin, Fraction& f);
private:
    int num;
    int den;
};
```

And  the operator overload:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& cin, Fraction& f)
{
    char ch;
    cin >> f.num >> ch >> f.den;
    return cin;
}
```

Visual studio is telling me f.num and f.den are inaccessible. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please extract a minimal example. A lot could go wrong in your code. Also, don't paraphrase but quote the error message (after searching with that very error message on the web in order to make sure you understand the issue). BTW: Assuming you have `using namespace std;` somewhere (bad practice), then your local parameter `cin` shadows the object with the same name from namespace `std`.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE] that we are able to see your context. Works [here](http://ideone.com/YLgc4T).

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have a local variable shadow the name of a standard library component. (edit: This was before Ulrich edited his post to indicate the same thing)

Comment: It isn't a good practice to name your variables and parameters with names like `cin`.

Comment: @underscore_d Well, besides the confusion it's leaving, it doesn't matter much from the point of syntactical correctness.

Comment: _@GarretRodgers_ Is intellisense fooling you?

Comment: @Garret Rodgers: Your code, as posted, is perfectly fine (aside from missing `std::`) and compiles without any problems in Visual Studio. If you are getting that error, it is rooted in something you are not showing us (additional namespaces, most likely). Under such circumstances any attempts to guess what's wrong are basically random and likely to cure the symptoms of the problem instead of fixing the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
friend istream& ::operator>>(istream& cin, Fraction& f);
```

add :: before operator, it mark that function operator>>() placed at global namespace

UPD: Another solution is add predefinition of functions and class, before class and function:

```
class Fraction;
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& cin, Fraction& f);
```

And of course do not forget that std:: prefix is need for interface (.h/.hpp). But using namespace std; if used only for implementation (.cpp)

Comment: Hmm, I thought the binary forms of operators (without implicit `this` LHS) couldn't possibly be considered to be declared within the class, so the global NS qualification wasn't needed. Maybe I'm wrong, or maybe OP has another namespace somewhere...

Comment: it worked on my gcc and as far as report from poster exists, it is worked on msvc